# How to make such Style reusable?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I designed my overlay popup, this is basically UserControl like this:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="400" MinHeight="150" MinWidth="250">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="42" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,26 L27,26 L27,0 L26,0 z" Fill="#FFFFFF" />
            <Border Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="27, 0, 0, 0" />
            <Image 
                Source="/Infrastructure.SL;component/Images/img_logo.png" 
                Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
            <Image 
                Source="/Infrastructure.SL;component/Images/img_tab_ornament.png"
                Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#23ceff">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.75" Direction="-45" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="1,0,1,1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#fcfff4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#cfddea" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>

            <my:DitatToolbar Grid.Row="1" Mode="Ok" Margin="1, 0, 1, 0" CaptionsOrientation="Horizontal"/>            

            <Image 
                Grid.Row="2" Height="32" Width="32" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Source="{Binding InteractionIconSource}"  />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Foreground="#3c3c3c" Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
```

I need to design a few windows like this with minor differences. Most of this XAML can be reused but I'm not sure how to approach it. The only unique XAML here is

```
<my:DitatToolbar Grid.Row="1" Mode="Ok" Margin="1, 0, 1, 0" CaptionsOrientation="Horizontal"/>            

                <Image 
                    Grid.Row="2" Height="32" Width="32" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Source="{Binding InteractionIconSource}"  />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Foreground="#3c3c3c" Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10" />
```

Everything else is chrome. I really want to have it in one place only. What can I use in Silverlight to achieve this reuse?

I feel like I need to create base control and inherit but not comfortable with XAML aspect. My code behind is pretty much blank, I'm using MVVM

Comment: Can you post an image of what this rendered control looks like? I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of approaches.  The best answer might depend on the overall requirements of your app.

A quick and possibly useful approach in a broader sense is to use a Frame.  To try it out, create a new Silverlight project and choose the "Silverlight Navigation Application" template.

Have a look at MainPage.xaml.  You could put your chrome in there, then have all the specific screens implemented in the same way as home.xaml etc.  The frame / navigation framework is pretty sweet if you need the functionality.  It can integrate with the browser, and allows for proper deep linking to screens.

Edit : It is a little bit of work but not too complicated to create a ContentCtronol.  A bit hard to explain everything here, but this link should do the trick : http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/05/creating-customized-usercontrols-deriving-from-contentcontrol-in-wpf-4

Comment: Navigation framework might be too much. I'm using PRISM, so I can use their Region stuff, but ideally I'd like something "manual". Do you have sample with ContentControl?

Comment: ContentControl with a custom ControlTemplate sounds like the best approach to me as well.